# LAST_INSERT_ID() not returning for all tags

Tags: php, mysql, bulkinsert

So I have 3 tables as follows.

```
TOPICS      TOPIC_TAGS    Tags
topic_id    tag_id        tag_id
topic_data  topic_id      tags
```

Right now I can successfully insert the topic_data into TOPICS, and the TAGS are being inserted like so...

```
tag_id    tags
1         this
2         is
3         a
4         test
```

But when I'm trying to insert the tag_ids into the TOPIC_TAGS table, it's only inserting the last one like this

```
topic_id  tag_id
0         4
```

And it's also not inserting the topic_id when the topic is inserted.

This is the form that posts the data.

```
<form method="post" action="add_topic.php">
<table>
<tr>
<td align="left"><b>Enter your Topic keywords.
    <ul id="topic" name="tags[]"></ul>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><textarea name="topic_data" cols="50" rows="3" id="topic_data" placeholder="What Topic are you talking about?"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" align="right">Invisipost: <input type="hidden" name="invisipost" value="0"><input type="checkbox" name="invisipost" value="1"> <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Talk" /> <input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Here is my code:

```
$tags = isset($_POST['tags']) ? $_POST['tags'] : null;

if (is_array($tags)) {
foreach ($tags as $t) {
    // Checking duplicate
     $sql_d = "SELECT * from tags where tags='$t'"; 
      $res=mysql_query($sql_d);
      $res = mysql_num_rows($res);
    if($res<1)
    {
    // escape the $t before inserting in DB
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tags (tags) VALUES('$t')";
    mysql_query($sql);
    }
 }
} else {
echo 'Invalid tag';
}
$sql_s = "SELECT * from tags where tag_id='$tags'";
$tag_id = isset($_GET['tag_id']) ? $_GET['tag_id'] : null;

if (is_array($tag_id)) {
foreach ($tag_id as $tid) {

    // escape the $t before inserting in DB
    $sql = "INSERT INTO topic_tags (tag_id) VALUES('$tid')";
    mysql_query($sql);
    }
 }

$sql="INSERT INTO topic_tags (tag_id)VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID())";
$result=mysql_query($sql);


$topic_data= htmlentities($_POST['topic_data']);
$posted_by = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$posted = "date_add(now(),INTERVAL 2 HOUR)";
$invisipost = isset($_POST['invisipost']) ? $_POST['invisipost'] : 0 ;

if (($topic_data=="")) 
echo "<h2>Opps...</h2><p>You did not fill out all the required fields.</p>";

else 
$sql="INSERT INTO topics(topic_data, posted_by, posted, invisipost)VALUES('$topic_data', '$posted_by', $posted, $invisipost)";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if($result){

$sql="INSERT INTO topic_tags (topic_id)VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID()) WHERE topic_tags.tag_id='". $_GET['tags'] ."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: `mysql_query` and such are being deprecated in php5.  You should switch to using object oriented statements, or procedural statements using `mysqli` instead of `mysql`.  For example, `mysqli_query("whatever");`

Comment: once i get the site fully functioning I plan too, do you have any suggestions on my problem I listed in my original post?

Comment: You are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks, and **you will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Use prepared/parameterized queries to avoid this problem entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **no more support** for **`mysql_*`** functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) or [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Since you're using **`mysql_*`**, you should use [**`mysql_real_escape_string`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to prevent injection.

---

**NOTE:** My example only covers the table information you provided at the top of your question, you will have to add any other columns yourself.

Using MySQLi and prepared statements you can easily prevent yourself from injection using prepared statements.

The `bind_param` takes care of the type of data you're inserting for example `i` stands for integer, `s` for string so for each `?` you have on your query you add it to the `bind_param` with it's respective type. **[Read more about `bind_param` here.](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)**

My test form:

```
<form method="post" action="add_topic.php">
<table>
<tr>
<td align="left"><b>Enter your Topic keywords.<br />
<input id="topic" name="tags">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><textarea name="topic_data" cols="50" rows="3" id="topic_data" placeholder="What Topic are you talking about?"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3" align="right">Invisipost: <input type="hidden" name="invisipost" value="0"><input type="checkbox" name="invisipost" value="1"> <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Talk" /> <input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

database.php:

```
<?php
// fill with your data
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = 'stackoverflow';
$db_pass = 'stackoverflow';
$db_name = 'stackoverflow';

$con = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_name);
if($con->connect_error)
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
```

add_topic.php:

```
<?php
include_once "database.php";
$tags = $_POST['tags'];
$topic_data = $_POST['topic_data'];
$ids = array();

if (!isset($topic_data))
{
    die("<h2>Opps...</h2><p>You did not fill out the topic data field.</p>");
}

if (!isset($tags))
{
    die("<h2>Opps...</h2><p>You did not fill out the tags field.</p>");
}

foreach (explode(' ', $tags) as $tag)
{
    if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT tag_id FROM tags WHERE tags=?"))
    {
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $tag);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id);
        $stmt->fetch();
        $stmt->close();
    }

    if ($id == 0)
    {
        if ($stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO tags (tags) VALUES(?)"))
        {
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $tag);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($id);
            $stmt->fetch();
            $ids[] = $stmt->insert_id;
            $stmt->close();
        }
    }
    else
        $ids[] = $id;
}

if ($stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO topics(topic_data) VALUES(?)"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $topic_data);
    if ($stmt->execute())
    {
        $topic_id = $stmt->insert_id;
        $stmt->close();
        foreach ($ids as $id)
        {
            if ($stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO topic_tags (topic_id, tag_id) VALUES(?, ?)"))
            {
                $stmt->bind_param("ii", $topic_id, $id);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->close();
            }
        }     
    }
    else
        $stmt->close();
}

echo "<h2>Topic successfully inserted</h2><p>The topic and tags have been inserted.</p>";
$con->close();
```

As you can see on my code, when I am checking for the tags, I am also retrieving the ids of the tags which already exist and storing them all into the array `$ids` to later reuse for the table `topic_tags`.

After I successfully insert the topic I retrieve the topic id and then insert all the tags id into the `topic_tags` table along with the topic id.

On my test form I am using a simple input for the tags however if you're using it as an array you can also change it from:

```
if (!isset($tags))
```

To:

```
if (!isset($tags) || !is_array($tags))
```

And change:

```
foreach (explode(' ', $tags) as $tag)
```

To:

```
foreach ($tags as $tag)
```

Comment: Thank you for your thought out post, I am trying your code and getting "Opps...
You did not fill out the tags field." the field is correctly named and there is data in it, I can't see in the code why I'd be getting the error.

Comment: @user2571547 on your HTML your tag is not a field its a listing element of HTML. `<ul id="topic" name="tags[]"></ul>`, `ul` is not a field.

Comment: Your example changed it to an input field, I was going off of that, I will put it back and retry.

Comment: @user2571547 nope I used input on my example because ul is not a field, if it works for you then you may be using some javascript or jquery to turn it into a field **and if you post your complete table information I can also update the code with the additional information you need to insert to make it easier for u to see how it works.**

Comment: I figured it out, I didn't out the mysql_ connect code, I did that, the data IS inserting as intended, but I am getting.. Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result() [mysqli-stmt.bind-result]: Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in /home3/topictal/public_html/add_topic.php on line 42 which is " $stmt->bind_result($id);"

Comment: @user2571547 did u change the SQL query there ? show me how is the query now.

Comment: I did not change it, it errored because there was no $con, I changed the connect file to include your code which has the $con, and it worked as far as inserting into the database, but still returned an error

Comment: @user2571547 can you update your question with how your code looks like now and I will spot you the errors will be easier this way.

Comment: @user2571547 if you changed tags to array see the bottom of my answer on how to change the code to accept tags as an array if not see my previous comment.